# How to sample Mean-Time-To Failure values from a Weibull Distribution with shape 1.5?

Tags: mathematics, statistics, failure-analysis, maintenance

I have a mean time to failure (MTTF) recorded from 100 systems which is 6.5 years. The shape parameter of my component is given with k = 1.3 (based on a list the from literature).

Now I want to sample (generate) further failure times based on a Weibull distribution. Can I use 6.5 years (=MTTF) as a scale parameter?

I would like to do this in python code, if anybody knows a solution for this.